# configure apache with sql

Tags: mysql, apache, configure

I am newly using Apache Tomcat6.0
I am unable to access sql database through my jsp and getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Tried steps at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

downloaded drivers mysql-connector-java-5.1.9 and mysql-5.0.85-win32 na dkept in tomcat\lib modified web.xml with context details
but this didinot help me.
Please suggest and provide steps if possible.

JSP code

```
Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:8080");
```

I am using sql server WampServer without a password and created databse and table successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the driver you need:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=99b21b65-e98f-4a61-b811-19912601fdc9